# Crashlytics class not recognized with Firebase Crashlytics SDK

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

With the Firebase Crashlytics SDK, the documentation explains how you can
[force a crash](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash?authuser=0&platform=android)

However, in the line:

```
Crashlytics.getInstance().crash();
```

Crashlytics is unrecognized and cannot be imported.

I tried switching to FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance() but there is no crash() method.

Note: Crashlytics is indeed set up properly - I am able to cause my own crash by looking up a view that does not exist and it is reported correctly.

Answer (score 8):

We have deprecated the force crash method in the new SDK. One example of a way to force a crash is manually throwing an exception

```
throw new RuntimeException("This is a crash");
```

Comment: Thanks Todd! Can you site documentation that supports this? As usual, google says 'try this!' yet doesn't change the documentation to specify old vs new usage.

Comment: you are right @galaxigirl, here yo have it [https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?authuser=0&platform=android]